# Removing the selected Item from the list

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2013

Basically it's a contact list, select the contact from the listbox and hit the remove button, deleting it from the list.

```
        private void btnRmv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try{

        listBox.Items.Remove(listBox.SelectedItems[0]);

        people.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);

        }
        catch { }
    }
```

This code seems to delete the Contacts from the listbox, but if I save my program and open it up again, the contact is back there. I am saving all the contacts in an Xml file. The program auto saves on exit, and does have a manual save button.

Thanks

Comment: remove from people list first? Because the SelectedIndex will change when you remove SelectedItems from listBox

Comment: Oh my. It's always the most simple things you miss. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show where your code is to save, but I imagine there is one contact missing - probably the one under the contact you wanted to remove?

Since you are using `SelectedIndex` AFTER removing the item from the list box, then some other item must be selected.

Try reversing the order:

```
private void btnRmv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        people.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
        listBox.Items.Remove(listBox.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove from the "people" first and then remove it from the list box or else take the selected index to a parameter. sample code is pasted below

```
    try
    {

    int _SeletedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex();

    listBox.Items.Remove(listBox.SelectedItems[0]);

    people.RemoveAt(_SeletedIndex);

    }
    catch { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing `selected item` first, so you lose the selected index and no item is deleted in list `people`.

Lets reorder the lines:

```
people.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);

listBox.Items.Remove(listBox.SelectedItems[0]);
```